# Property __key__ is empty with node

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I created a simple datastore (projects) with one string property (name) and some example datasets.

When I use `gql` I can select the `__key__` and can query by the `__key__` property.

But when I select the data from nodejs, the `__key__` property is empty.

### Problem

**setup:**

```
const datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')({
  projectId: 'my-project',
  keyFilename: `path/to/keyfile.json`
});
```

**not working:** selecting all datasets with key-only query:

```
const query = datastore.createQuery('Projects').select('__key__');

datastore.runQuery(query).then( results => {

  console.log('RESULTS:', results[0]);
})
```

**result:**

```
RESULTS: [ {}, {}, {} ]
```

A normal query works as expected:

```
datastore.runQuery(query).then( results => {

  console.log('RESULTS:', results[0]);
})
```

.. but here also the `__key__` property is missing:

```
RESULTS: [ { name: 'Test Projekt 1' },
  { name: 'Test Projekt 2' },
  { name: 'Test Projekt 3' } ]
```

## Question

How do I select the `__key__` property with the `@google-cloud/datastore` module correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Node, but found the below sample code in the [API doc](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/1.0.0/datastore). Perhaps it helps:

> A keys-only query returns just the keys of the result entities instead
>   of the entities themselves, at lower latency and cost.

```
var keysOnlyQuery = datastore.createQuery('Lion').select('__key__');

datastore.runQuery(keysOnlyQuery, function(err, entities) {
  var keys = entities.map(function(entity) {
    return entity[datastore.KEY];
  });
});
```

> If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.

```
datastore.runQuery(query).then(function(data) {
  var entities = data[0];
});
```